# Accessing an array in glut

Tags: c++, glut

I am new to glut and I am working on creating an animation of drones flying in the air. I am storing these drones (called UAVs) in an array that I initialize in my main function. I quickly realized this array was inaccessible once I am inside the glut main loop. I tried to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668388/drawing-an-array-of-objects-in-open-gl-glut) for an answer, but I am still a little confused. Here are some code snippets, if anyone has any advice on how to properly initialize this array so I can access it in glut I would appreciate it.

```
// all in main.cpp
// ECE_UAV.cpp is a separate file 
// declare the uav class array to store the information of all uavs
ECE_UAV* uavs = new ECE_UAV[numUAVs];

void drawUAVs()
{
    //updateUAVs();
    for (int i = 0; i < numUAVs; i++)
    {
        // traverse the uavs class array
        // call the class's member public function to draw the uav
        // using the information stored in that uav class
        // <--------- This cout is incorrect, and I believe it is because I don't know how 
        // ---------- to initialize the array properly for glut to use
        // ---------- O/P: "Drawing UAV 2 {-6.27744e+66, -6.27744e+66, -6.27744e+66}"
        cout << "Drawing UAV " << i << " {" << uavs[i].getX() << ", " << uavs[i].getY() << ", " << uavs[i].getZ() << "}" << endl;
        uavs[i].draw();
    }
}


void renderScene()
{
    //... other things
    drawUAVs();
    //... other things
}
    

// mainOpenGL
void mainOpenGL(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // init
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // set mode
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    // set window size and location
    ...

    // create window, set background color and title
    ...

    // set and enable modes
    ...

    // my lighting
    ...

    // enable lighting
    ...

    // set up texture part
    ...

    // set recall functions
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene); // <-------- This is where I call my render
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutTimerFunc(100, timerFunction, 0);

    // enter the opengl main loop
    // never return
    glutMainLoop();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        cout << "Entering main method..." << endl;
        // init the UAV class array
        // including initializing the uav's location
        for (int i = 0; i < numUAVs; i++)
        {
            double x = i % 3 * 24.4 - 24.4;
            double y = i / 3 * 27.5 - 55.0;
            double z = 0;
            uavs[i].initLocation(x, y, z);
           // <---------- I know that these are set correct, but the don't match the above cout
           // ----------- O/P: "Drawing UAV 0 {-24.4, -55, 0}"
            cout << "UAV " << i << " Initialized to {" << uavs[i].getX() << ", " << uavs[i].getY() << ", " << uavs[i].getZ() << "}" << endl;
        }

    // enter opengl main loop
     mainOpenGL(argc, argv);
}
```

If you need more code please let me know, I just tried to provide what I felt was relevant.

Comment: Where is `uavs` array declared/defined?

Comment: I'll edit this. I have it defined as a global variable in my main.cpp, but all of the methods for the UAVs are in ECE_UAV.cpp

Comment: How is `ECE_UAV` defined as?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I fixed my issue. I added a global variable init_UAVs and edited my drawUAVs() to look like the code below. It is not a perfect solution, but it works for my project so far.

```
// Global variable
int init_UAVs = 1;

// function to draw uavs
void drawUAVs()
{
    if (init_UAVs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numUAVs; i++)
            {
                double x = i % 3 * 24.4 - 24.4;
                double y = i / 3 * 27.5 - 55.0;
                double z = 0;
                uavs[i].initLocation(x, y, z);   
            }
        init_UAVs--;
    }    

    updateUAVs();

    for (int i = 0; i < numUAVs; i++)
    {
        // traverse the uavs class array
        // call the class's member public function to draw the uav
        // using the information stored in that uav class
          
        uavs[i].draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using C++, I would suggest to use classes. This way you can initialize stuff in the class constructors and also, it will encapsulate related functionalities in a single class.

Comment: Good idea. I do have a lot of information for kinematics calculations already in my UAV struct, so I could add one more. Thanks for the advice!